# How to get the percentage of each class/pixel area in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

This is my script

```
    // Select the class from the classified image
   var bare5 = classified16.select('classification').eq(3);
  Map.addLayer(bare5);

// Calculate the pixel area in square kilometer
var area_bare5 = bare5.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e6);

// Reducing the statistics for study area
var stat5 = area_bare5.reduceRegion ({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
geometry: Densu,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9,
 });

// Get the sq km area for Bareland
print('Bareland Area(in sq.km)', stat5);

//To add all classes from the classified image    
var Sum = classified16.select('classification').eq(0).add(classified16.select('classification').eq(2))
                 .add(classified16.select('classification').eq(3));


 var total = Sum.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e6);

 var total_Sum = total.reduceRegion ({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
geometry: Densu,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9,
});

print('Total Area(in sq.km)', total_Sum);// This gave me the total pixel area(km2) of all the 3 classes(vegetation, bare land and water body)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provided a complete, working example. I will assume you've got your classification working and your areas are correct. The percentage you simply calculate like this:

```
var barelandArea = ee.Number(3)
var totalArea = ee.Number(10)

var barelandPercent = barelandArea
  .divide(totalArea)
  .multiply(100)

print('bareland %', barelandPercent)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr.Daniel. It worked perfectly.